# Prevent element from showing if partially obstructed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any code (either CSS or JS) that can prevent an element from loading/being visible if it is partially obstructed from view?

On my site [newsoftheuniverse.blogspot.ca](https://newsotuniverse.blogspot.ca/) , I have a carrousel that shows a few headlines at a time before removing one to the left. However (depending on your screen resolution) often the last headline gets cut off. Is there some code I can add to either #carousel ul li or .river or .pible to prevent a cut-off headline from appearing?

CSS:

```
#carousel{height:55px; width:100% !important; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto}
#carousel ul li{width:300px !important; height:70px; overflow:hidden;}
.cozo {background:rgb(244,244,244); padding:8px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin: 0 5% 0 5%; width: 90%}
.river{font-size:12px; line-height:18.8px;}
.river img{width:65px; height:55px; float:left; margin: 0 12px 12px 0;}
.pible{width:90%;}
.river a{color:#777;}
.river a:hover{color:$(link.color);}
```

Javascript:

```
<div id='carousel'>
<div class='beek1'>
<script>
document.write(&quot; &lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>   
</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {  $(document).ready(function(){
$(&quot;#carousel&quot;).jCarouselLite({
    auto:2600,
    scroll: 1,
    speed: 2600,    
    visible: 4,
    start: 0,
    circular: true,
    btnPrev: &quot;#previous_button&quot;,
    btnNext: &quot;#next_button&quot;
    });
    })})(jQuery)    
</script> 
<div class='clear'/>
```

Comment: I see that you use a jQuery plugin jCarouselLite. I am not familiar with it but I wonder if the auto scroll actually overrides the css you have done to carousel because from what I understand, `overflow: hidden` should be good to go. I think one of the solution is to find out px width of headlines and set speed according to them so that every scroll steps will be perfect.